# How to fixe Cocoapods issues to start a react native project

Tags: ruby, react-native, cocoapods, react-native-cli

When I start the project and run it, I encounter a problem. Initially, I am prompted to install Cocoapods, and when I press yes, I encounter errors related to the failed installation of Ruby gems. Subsequently, I receive the message "Error installing pods failed. This doesn't affect project initialization, and you can safely proceed." Following this, I run the command "cd "/Users/rabiegharghar/Desktop/react native/app/ios"" and launch the app. The simulator starts, but it fails to create the app.(I know that my question does not hve a lot of details this is du to my lake of experience it's my first React Native project, so i will be glad to provide any additionnel informations that could help to understand and the problem)

I tried to update the Ruby version but it dosent work

Comment: What “errors related to the failed installation of Ruby gems” do you “encounter” specifically? Please share the full error messages, including the stack trace. What version of Ruby do you have installed and what version of Ruby did you try to install? What version of Cocoapods do you have installed? What command did you run, when you got the error?

Comment: I was finally able to launch the application on the virtual device. However, the issue is that Cocoapods is still not installed. When I try to install it manually and run the command (bundle install), I get the following error:An error occurred while installing json (2.7.1), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install json -v '2.7.1' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'` succeeds before bundling.

The Gem version I have is 2.6.10. I have tried several ways to update it, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Did you try to run the `gem install json -v '2.7.1' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'` command? What exactly happened when you did?

Comment: 1 error generated.
make: *** [generator.o] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/json-2.7.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/extensions/universal-darwin-22/2.6.0/json-2.7.1/gem_make.out

Comment: when i try to update the version of Ruby that's the error i get : Error running '__rvm_make -j8',
please read /Users/apple/.rvm/log/1703688905_ruby-2.7.2/make.log

There has been an error while running make. Halting the installation.

Comment: The error message says: _please read /Users/apple/.rvm/log/1703688905_ruby-2.7.2/make.log_. What does the log file at `/Users/apple/.rvm/log/1703688905_ruby-2.7.2/make.log` say?

Comment: it's a very big file i could not copy it here

Comment: i tried so many ways to update ruby version but it still dosent work